# MapKit: go to max zoom

Tags: ios7, mapkit

I have tried a few solutions but haven't found one that works for me. Basically, when a button is pressed on my mapview, I want to zoom in as far as MapKit allows, with the user location centered. I keep trying to manipulate the distance parameters, but it seems below a certain point that no longer works...the map view will only zoom to a certain distance, but I can manually pinch and zoom further beyond that. Obviously I don't expect it to give me a 10x10m map...but as close as possible.

Actually, ideally I'd like to do this in combination with using the "follow with heading" tracking mode...but I've found that setting this property will automatically set the zoom level to some predefined point, which is annoying. I think I'll have to manually track heading and rotate the map...a little frustrating that the API doesn't give us a little more flexibility. And it seems like "[mapView maxZoom]" would be a really useful call, but I've found no such thing...what am I missing?

```
-(void)zoomAndCenterMap
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 10, 10);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];
    [self.mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `maxZoom` API does indeed not exist in MapKit. I've added a method to a subclass of `MKMapView` over in [another project](https://github.com/mapbox/mbxmapkit/blob/31be0407a32e0e0aaea0f82e4e9f63f59993b6e7/MBXMapKit.m#L496-L499) that might be of use. Then you could at least figure out what the max zoom level **is** and maybe programmatically go to it.

Comment: Seems like a rather big oversight to me...but what can you do? Thanks for the link!